# Using Proc.new in if condition in after_create filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have come across the following code in CodeSchools tutorial .

```
class Following < ActiveRecord::Base

   after_create :queue_new_follower_email,
      if: Proc.new {|f| f.followed_user.receive_emails? }

 end
```

I'm confused . What is the f variable and where has it come from ? Is it a reference to the current model object ? If yes, How should I have guessed it ?(Documentation/source code ?)

I'm aware of the syntax of the Proc block , but I'm confused as to where the 'f' variable has come from ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails passes the model as an argument.

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

```
class Firm < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Destroys the associated clients and people when the firm is destroyed
  before_destroy { |record| Person.destroy_all "firm_id = #{record.id}"   }
  before_destroy { |record| Client.destroy_all "client_of = #{record.id}" }
end
```